# C++ .exe with .dll not running outside of CLion

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, clion

The program runs just fine when started from inside CLion although it is refusing to run by double clicking the .exe with this error being shown when I try to run it:

The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE12find_last_ofEPKcyy could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\steppers\projects\cyan\bin\libcyan_engine.dll.

It looks to me like an issue with a standard lib or something judging by the basic_string bit but I'm at a complete loss here now.

Here is my root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(cyan_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(engine)
include_directories(engine/include)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(cyan_test ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(cyan_test cyan_engine)
```

And the engine subdirectory's:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(cyan_engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(lib/glfw-3.2.1)
include_directories(lib/glfw-3.2.1/include)

add_definitions("-fPIC")
add_subdirectory(lib/g3log-1.2)
include_directories(lib/g3log-1.2/src)

include_directories(include)

set(SOURCE_FILES <src files here>)
add_library(cyan_engine SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(cyan_engine glfw g3logger)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(cyan_engine ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one copy of either the exe or the dll lying around? Running from CLion might have a different current directory than when you run the exe directly, and that might cause an outdated exe or dll to be used.

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. When it runs it shows the .exe and i'm just clicking on it. I'm not sure if CLion is doing anything else in the background.

Comment: One way to get a better idea is just monitor the execution. On a successful run use a tool such as Process Explorer to get the exact location of the exe, the dll, and the current directory of the process. When the launch fails, you can use Process Monitor to see which executables were used. Once you're able to detect the differences, it should be easier to fix the issue.

Comment: Awesome, used process monitor to find the missing mingw dll that was being used. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot! (libstdc++-6.dll if you were curious)